# Sobolev trace condition

Tags: sobolev-spaces

If we have two functions $f,g \in W^{1,m}(E)$ in some domain $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ who have a trace on $\partial E$ with $f\leq g$ on $\partial E$. Is it then always possible to still have $f>g$ everywhere in $E$ ($f$, $g$ not continuous)?

Comment: Not if $m$ is so large that $W^{1, m}\subset C^0$, obviously.

Comment: What do you mean by _is it always possible_? For example, if it happens that $f \equiv g$, then no, it's not possible to have $f > g$.